# XCode UIImageView not in right position after orientation change

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, centering

I have a problem in my application. I am trying to make a picture show up and let it fade after 2 seconds after certain actions in the application get completed, this all works fine. However, when the picture is on the screen and I rotate my device, the picture's location does not get updated to the new center of the screen, it's not a huge problem but it just looks really bad. I have listed my code below.

```
+(void)fadeOut:(int)type{
//create subImageView
UIImageView *myImageView = nil;
switch (type) {
    case 1:
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"skipoverlay.png"]];
        break;
    case 2:
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkoverlay.png"]];
        break;
    case 3:
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"endoftask.png"]];
        break;
    case 4:
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"startoverlay"]];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
UIWindow *mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
myImageView.center=mainWindow.center;
myImageView.tag=11;
[mainWindow insertSubview:myImageView aboveSubview:mainWindow];

//add fade out animation
[UIView beginAnimations: @"Fade Out" context:nil];

// wait for time before begin
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];

// duration of animation
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: It will not update until you update its center position again after device rotation.

Comment: How would I update it here though? This function is not in any controller, it just gets the keyWindow, so I'm not sure where I would check the "viewWillTransitionToSize" in this case? I'm pretty new to XCode and Objective-C.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're adding it to the "main window" instead of the current view? If so, you may want to look at this: https://github.com/hfossli/AGWindowView ... I haven't used it, but from the description it looks like it could help.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has to be in the "main window", this was just recommended to me by someone else. Basically what's happening is: Button gets clicked -> We go to a new view -> Image gets displayed above the new view and fades after 2 seconds.

The new view we go to after clicking the button depends on how we got to the button (so really it just gets the previous view).

Comment: Try to clarify what you're doing... what is "we go to a new view"? Are you using a NavigationController? Are you showing a Modal view? Is it a TabBar structure? (by the way, if you include @DonMag in your comment (or whatever username you're replying to), then I would get notified).

Comment: @DonMag I'm using a navigation controller, so when the button gets pressed, we get sent back to the previous view. I wish I could explain it better but I just got given this big existing project, in a language I've never seen, and I'm trying to work the bugs out.

Comment: hmmm... you are showing a view... a button is tapped... a new view "slides in from the right" (standard navigation controller action)? When it has finished sliding in, a new view is shown over-laid on it? and that view has a button? and tapping that button fades-out the view and the underneath view slides back out to the right?

Comment: @DonMag No the same button that loads the previous view also causes an UIImageView to show up with a picture that fades out after 2 seconds.

Comment: @JordyElst - I'd be happy to try and help, but I'm still not clear on what is going on. You said `navigation controller` ... has a view been pushed onto the stack, and now you want a button-tap to show an overlay image, have it fade out after (or over the course of) 2 seconds, and trigger a pop navigation as if the user tapped the standard Back button?

Comment: @DonMag Figured I'd make a video to show you the problem I'm experiencing. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uud46Z1Dn0I

As you see if the image is up during the rotation it gets put in an odd spot. It is in the middle again the next time it pops up, but then when rotating the same thing happens. Everything works, just the position during rotation gets messed up.